# Inline row editing using ng table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

**Hi Everyone,**

**I am trying to implementing inline row edit using ng table**

**When I click on edit icon then I changed the values then I click on save icon I am gettin below error**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'untrack' of undefined

Please find plunker
[Inline row edit using ng table for details coding](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQyEeJ?editors=101)

```
<table
        class="alignment table table-striped table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed editable-table demoTable"
        ng-table="tableParams" ng-show="showTable" ng-form="tableForm"  demo-tracked-table="tableTracker">
        <colgroup>
        <col width="45%" />
        <col width="45%" />
        <col width="10%" />

    </colgroup>

    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data" ng-form="rowForm" demo-tracked-table-row="row">

        <td data-title="'INR Rate'" ng-switch="row.isEditing" ng-class="inrRate.$dirty ? 'bg-warning' : ''" ng-form="inrRate" demo-tracked-table-cell>
            <span ng-switch-default class="editable-text">{{row.INRRate}}</span>
            <div class="controls" ng-class="inrRate.$invalid && inrRate.$dirty ? 'has-error' : ''" ng-switch-when="true">
                <input  type="number" name="inrRate" ng-model="row.INRRate" class="editable-input form-control input-sm" required />
            </div>
        </td>
```

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? is so please post your answer Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem but no luck after investigation on sample code.
I modified the code and it works fine until now.

1. Do not use "ngTableSimpleList". It is just a data set for table which defined in sample code by author.
2. It seems tableTracker.untrack(row) can be removed safely.
3. However,`var originalRow = resetRow(row, rowForm);` would get a nil value which cause the value doesn't recover correctly,  since `_.findWhere` is an asynchronous method. So I replace it with `for` loop.

   ```
   function resetRow(row, rowForm) {
       row.isEditing = false;
       rowForm.$setPristine();
       //self.tableTracker.untrack(row);
       for ( let i in originalData){
           if(originalData[i].id === row.id){
               return originalData[i]
           }
       }
       //return _.findWhere(originalData, function(r) {
        //   return r.id === row.id;
       //});
   }
   ```

Comment: NB. _.findWhere in that example is not working! the lodash 3.10.1 findWhere method accepts different params. Btw It's sync. See this issue: https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/912

Answer (score 2):

You were injecting `NgTableParams` instead of `ngTableParams` - see working: [fixed example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQyEeJ?editors=101)

```
demoController.$inject = ["ngTableParams", "ngTableSimpleList", "$scope"];
```

Comment: when I click on edit and save or cancel I am getting table tracker undefined actually this is my issue